# How to combine multiple different numpy arrays along a single common dimension, while setting unique variables as separate dimensions

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have multiple different `numpy` arrays, all with different shapes and containing different information. But all contain a `'timestamp'` axis.

For example, I have 2 arrays, a, b as follows:

- `a = np.array([[1,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]],[2,[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]],[3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]],[4,[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]])`
- `b = np.array([[1,0],[2,1],[3,1],[4,0]])`

I want to combine them to create the following

```
([
    [1, [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 0]], [2, [[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 1]], [3, [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 1]], [4, [[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 0]]
])
```

I have been going in circles and have tried using different techniques like `vstack`, `concatenation`, as well as a bunch of others, but have not been successful.

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the previous answer using a zip solved it for you but it works only if the 2 lists have the "index element" in the same order. In case they are not (or if there are few indexes missing), the zip will not work properly.

Try this.

```
import itertools

[[i[0][0],[i[0][1],i[1][1]]] for i in itertools.product(a,b) if i[1][0]==i[0][0]]
```

This is basically the same as taking a join on the index element.

```
[[1, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 0]],
 [2, [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 1]],
 [3, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1]],
 [4, [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't combine these with ordinary `numpy` functions.  `a` is object dtype containing lists, a mix of row indicies and and lists.  And the desired array is even 'worse':

```
In [172]: a = np.array([[1,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]],[2,[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]],[
     ...: 3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]],[4,[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]])               
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Thats v 1.19dev warning.

```
In [173]: b = np.array([[1,0],[2,1],[3,1],[4,0]])
```

The best way to construct an usual object dtype array is to initialize the basic shape, and fill it.  Filling from lists usually works better than from arrays (if avoids some broadcasting errors):

```
In [186]: c = np.empty((4,2), object)                                                   
In [187]: c                                                                             
Out[187]: 
array([[None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
In [188]: c[:,0] = b[:,0]                                                               
In [189]: c                                                                             
Out[189]: 
array([[1, None],
       [2, None],
       [3, None],
       [4, None]], dtype=object)
In [190]: c[:,1] = [[A[1],B[1]] for A,B in zip(a,b)]                                    
In [191]: c                                                                             
Out[191]: 
array([[1, list([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 0])],
       [2, list([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 1])],
       [3, list([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1])],
       [4, list([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 0])]],
      dtype=object)
```

Actually, making a list of lists is simpler:

```
In [192]: [[B[0], [A[1], B[1]]] for A,B in zip(a,b)]                                    
Out[192]: 
[[1, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 0]],
 [2, [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 1]],
 [3, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1]],
 [4, [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 0]]]
```

Comment: This method only works if the 2 lists have the same order of index element (the 1,2,3,4 which are the first elements in each sublist)